# Where does this Alan Watts audio clip come from?

Tags: reference-request, quote, love

I'm trying to locate the source of an Alan Watts quote/audio clip that has been used in numerous YouTube edits. It is referenced in some places as the 'Falling Into Love' lecture, but there is no such lecture listed on the Alan Watts website, or anywhere else legitimate (that I can find, anyhow) - just on YouTube and personal blogs, etc. who I think are basically all just referencing each other.

The quote is:

> "Well now really when we go back into falling in love. And say, it's
>   crazy. Falling. You see? We don't say "rising into love". There is in
>   it, the idea of the fall. And it goes back, as a matter of fact, to
>   extremely fundamental things. That there is always a curious tie at
>   some point between the fall and the creation. Taking this ghastly risk
>   is the condition of there being life. You see, for all life is an act
>   of faith and an act of gamble. The moment you take a step, you do so
>   on an act of faith because you don't really know that the floor's not
>   going to give under your feet ... so, actually, therefore, the course
>   of wisdom, what is really sensible, is to let go, is to commit
>   oneself, to give oneself up and that's quite mad. So we come to the
>   strange conclusion that in madness lies sanity."

My daughter came across this on YouTube and loved it so much she used it as a voice over for a portion of her major HSC dance film assessment. The problem is, we now have to locate the complete lecture so that we can purchase a copy of it and obtain public performance/licensing rights (for a potential awards night performance), but after weeks and weeks of googling obsessively trying to find it, listening to literally hours and hours of Alan Watts lectures on YouTube, and making multiple attempts at contacting the Alan Watts group directly, i've come up empty.

Various people online have suggested that it is part of the 'Spectrum of Love' lecture, but i've listened to that entire lecture and couldn't find this section. I also tried any other love/relationship-related lectures he gave, but still nothing. The most useful thing I found was an extended version of the clip, titled 'Love and Marriage', which contains the bit we're after, but this isn't an entire lecture, and therefore isn't listed on the Alan Watts website for purchase. I'm assuming that this is from another lecture that has been cut in half (this clip is about 30mins, and most lectures are about an hour long) and then re-named, but there is no reference to the original lecture anywhere.

We're getting slightly desperate, as the cut-off date for submitting the purchase/licensing information is fast approaching, and as it stands I can't even tell them which lecture it's from! If anyone could give me any sort of help with this I would be eternally grateful.

[This is the YouTube video my daughter originally found](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Uhahu0Pos4&t=1s).

[This is the 'Love and Marriage' clip that I found](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhdj1Z5TUG8).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to originate in this lecture:

https://www.alanwatts.org/searchable/1-4-4-divine-madness/

The audio of which can be purchased here:
https://alan-watts-electronic-university.myshopify.com/products/philosophy-and-society

See here for more information about that website. maybe you can contact them to ask about licensing:
https://www.alanwatts.org/about/

Note that the text that you are interested in appears to end the lecture.

Comment: That's it! I cannot thank you enough, you have absolutely saved me. I've purchased the lecture pack, and i'll have a go at contacting them through the website you found in the morning (I had previously been trying to contact them via alanwatts.com, not alanwatts.org - i'm not sure if these are essentially the same site/run by the same people, but i'll give it a go anyhow).

Thank you thank you thank you. You have honestly made my day, I am SO grateful! :D